# Table structure for different order statistics

Tags: mysql

I am creating a marketplace and I would like to have different type of statistics like this:

1. products more sell
2. categories of products more sell
3. user that bought this product bought even this prodcuts
4. user prefered categories of products
5. user recent products boughts

to limit the creation of table i was thinking on this unique table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_stats` (
  `id_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_seller` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_subcat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_ord` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is this table structure enough to obtain all the parameters needed for the type on statistics write before?

Comment: What do "products more sell" and "categories of products more sell" mean?

Comment: i mean product and categories of products more bought by the users

Comment: You mean the most popular products and categories?

Comment: yes can say even most popular, the 10 products more bought into the shop will appear in this area. for the points 1,2,4,5 i almost sure that with this table strcuture will function, is about the point 3 that i am not sure that this structure its enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these can be achieved with your proposed table structure. I've included example queries - they only return IDs because I don't know anything about the other tables in the database. I hope I have understood what you want the queries to do - let me know if not.

**1. products more sell**

This query shows the top 10 products purchased

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), id_product 
FROM 
    order_stats
GROUP BY 
    id_product
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**2. categories of products more sell**

This query shows the top 10 categories of products purchased

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*), id_cat 
FROM 
    order_stats
GROUP BY 
    id_cat
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**3. user that bought this product bought even this prodcuts**

This query shows the IDs of products purchased by users who also purchased product ID 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id_product
FROM
    order_stats
WHERE
    order_stats.id_user IN (SELECT id_user FROM order_stats WHERE id_product = 2)
AND
    order_stats.id_product != 2;
```

**4. user prefered categories of products**

This query shows the top 10 categories of products purchased by user 1:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*), id_cat
FROM
    order_stats
WHERE
    order_stats.id_user = 1
GROUP BY 
    id_cat
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**5. user recent products boughts**

This query shows the 10 most recent products purchased by user 1:

```
SELECT
    id_product
FROM
    order_stats
WHERE
    order_stats.id_user = 1
ORDER BY 
    date_ord DESC
LIMIT 10;
```